# Migrate messaging security from Glassfish to JBoss 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jboss7.x

I am new to JBoss 7. I have already done Messaging Security in Glassfish for my web application. I would like to move my application to JBoss 7.

Could anyone guide me to achieve Messaging security in JBoss 7?

Answer (score 1):

JBoss 7 uses HornetQ as a message broker, so you need to look at its documentation. JBoss 7 has a very nice GUI console that enables to do quite a lot of administration tasks (but CLI interface gives access to more config options).

For a short introduction how to configure messaging on JBoss 7 with basic security setting see this article: http://www.techartifact.com/blogs/2012/10/jboss-as-7-setting-up-hornetq-jms.html.

If you need custom authentication/authorization, you need to create your custom security application realm: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Security+Realms

Comment: Let me explain you what am i expecting to do.
1. When I request my application (by sending request from client- browser), the request would be redirected to my own class(Authorization.class) by application server(glassfish - Message Security) where have done some kind of authorization (XXX.jar). Once the request have been authorized then only the request will go to my application.
2. So please guide me to achive the same in jboss7

Comment: If you need custom authentication/authorization, you need to create your custom security application realm: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Security+Realms

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would like to implement custom authorization by implementing ServerAuthModule. So please give me an idea to implement this in jboss7

Comment: do anybody have an idea on how to implement javax.security.auth.message.module.ServerAuthModule in jboss7 because i would like to validate a request which is coming to my application.